# Any banks in Hong Kong offer credit cards to non-HK residents?

Tags: credit-card, non-resident, documents, hong-kong, application-process

Any way to get a credit card in HK without holding a HK ID card?

Are there any local regulations preventing banks from offering that, or do the banks simply not want to bother? I tried HSBC and was rejected for that reason.

Comment: Rejected for what reason? Lack of ID card or HSBC simply has no interest in offering it? Sounds like they might have given you the answer you seek already...

Comment: p.s. In the online application for any of HSBC's HK credit cards, one of the questions is "Do you hold a permanent HK ID card?" .. and selecting "No" does not appear to abort the application process.  Did you try online, or in a bank?  Sometimes the nice person behind the counter at the bank doesn't know correct policy, they make an assumption instead.  See https://www.hsbc.com.hk/1/2/hk/cards/application?WABFormEntryCommand=cmd_init if you want to try an online application.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea For HSBC, the application form now can't be submitted without HK ID number filled in:

`Please enter your HK ID number.
Please enter the digit of your HK ID`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It varies.  You may have asked a bank that, by their own policy, requires the ID card.  But, apparently, there should be banks that permit a passport to be used instead of the HK ID card.  Refer to [Angloinfo.com - Banking in Hong Kong](http://hongkong.angloinfo.com/information/money/banking/opening-an-account/):

> [...]
>
> **Opening a Bank Account**
>
> Some retail banks *[in Hong Kong]* provide account
>   opening forms which can be downloaded
>   from their websites. Requirements and
>   criteria for opening an account vary
>   from bank to bank. However, the
>   standard documents needed for a
>   savings or current account are:
>
> - Hong Kong Identification Card *or
>     passport*
> - proof of Hong Kong
>     address or address in home country
> - application form
>
> *Note: It is not necessary to be a
>   resident in Hong Kong to open a bank
>   account.*  *[emphasis mine]*
>
> [...]

Comment: "... or passport... It is not necessary to be a resident in Hong Kong to open a bank account"--It would be very helpful if someone names the banks which allow opening a bank account without a HK ID or HKSAR Passport.